# Do I need to update FIM 2010 in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, fim

I was wondering if I need to update FIM 2010 that comes with SharePoint 2013? There are some patches available [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/iamsupport/idmbuildversions/) and the version I have is 4.0.2450.51, which is even below the RTM version.
My SharePoint 2013 farm is on Jan 2018 CU, so I assume I cannot blame our update sluggishness for outdated FIM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you never patch FIM directly. Only apply SharePoint cumulative updates. Those will patch the built-in FIM instance as required.

Comment: That's exactly what was my own understanding, thanks for confirmation!